# How do I echo in php a jquery dialog box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

For a php project I am working on, I am trying to echo a popup window if an sql record is successful. I have been able to get this to work with javaScript alert but that’s not what I want, The JavaScript is preventing the rest of the page from loading until OK is clicked plus I would prefer to style a jQuery dialog instead.

Here is what does work in the php but not what I want:

```
$msg = "Success!";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $msg . '"); </script>';

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

I have found this below to prevent pop up until page loads, but it does not work:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function(){ alert("' . $msg . ' "));}</script>';
```

I am trying to get a jquery dialog to popup. Here is the basic jquery dialog from their website not working. It just displays the text in the paragraph tag. (I was planning on customizing it after its working):

```
echo '<script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
            });
        </script>'
        .'<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
                <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the x icon.</p>
        </div>';
```

Comment: do you load the jquery library?

Comment: yes <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: make sure you are including the JQuery Core and the JQuery UI libraries

Comment: Thank you Wazani, I was missing the UI library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user Wazani, I simply forgot to include the jquery UI library in addition to the core.